# embedding absolute path for shared libraries

Tags: c, cross-compiling, gnu-toolchain

Using a vendor provided cross-compiling toolchain (apparently an OpenEmbedded derivative), I'm unable to embed the absolute path to third-party (open source, compiled in house)libraries. With the following gcc command line:

```
arm-linux-gcc test_connect_send.o gprs_connect.o \
    /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libgprs_stuff.so \
    /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libpower_supply_stuff.so \
    /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libgsm_stuff.so \
    /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libtcp_stuff.so \
    /package/host/aspl.es/vortex-1.1.0/lib/libvortex-1.1.so \
    /package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0  -o test_connect_send
```

objdump says:

```
Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED      /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libgprs_stuff.so
  NEEDED      /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libpower_supply_stuff.so
  NEEDED      /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libgsm_stuff.so
  NEEDED      /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/libtcp_stuff.so
  NEEDED      libvortex-1.1.so.0
  NEEDED      libaxl.so.0
  NEEDED      libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED      libc.so.6
```

Notice how my vendor's libraries do have their full path, while aspl's don't. Also, notice how the name embedded is different from the one I specified on the command line. I'd like to know why (who is messing with my paths), and how to solve it.

p.s.: I know about RPATH, that's not the answer I'm looking for

Comment: Does your gcc compiler have the -print-file-name flag? Try this:

arm-gcc-linux -print-file-name=/package/host/aspl.es/vortex-1.1.0/lib/libvortex-1.1.so

BTW, does the program run successfully? (it has /package/host/myvendor.com in the DT_RPATH ?)

Comment: I can't tell you why that's happening, but you really should not specify absolute paths to the libs like that. use -L /package/host/myvendor.com/API-R-2.0.0/Release/Libraries/ -lbgprs_stuff and similar.

Comment: There are options ('`-v`' IIRC) to see the exact command lines passed to component programs invoked by `gcc`.  Try using that to see if you can spot a difference in how the 'myvendor' and 'aspl' libraries are passed to '`ld`' (or in the surrounding options).  Something has to be telling the loader to treat the two sets of libraries differently.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the vendor supplied libs set the SONAME to the full installed path.

Answer (score 0):

arm-linux-gcc -print-file-name does not show anything suprising:

arm-linux-gcc -print-file-name=/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0.0.0 
/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0.0.0
arm-linux-gcc -print-file-name=/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0.0
/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0.0
arm-linux-gcc -print-file-name=/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0
/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so.0
arm-linux-gcc -print-file-name=/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so
/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/libaxl.so

The resulting binary does not run without LD_LIBRARY_PATH defined, nor does it have a DT_RPATH (although that might certainly help, suggestions?)

I don't want to rely on /etc/ld.so.conf being properly set, and thus I want absolute paths everywhere.

Note that suggestions might well point to the compilation of the third-party libraries, which as of now are compiled with:

make distclean; LDFLAGS=-L/package/host/myvendor.com/arm9-linux-toolchain-2.1/prefix/arm-linux/lib CC=/package/host/myvendor.com/arm9-linux-toolchain-2.1/prefix/bin/arm-linux-gcc ~/wd/sources/contrib/axl/configure --prefix=/shared/syst/arm9-linux-abtrack/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6 --host=armv4tl-unknown-linux-gnu --disable-axl-knife --disable-axl-babel --disable-axl-log --disable-axl-test && make

make distclean; AXL_LIBS="-L/shared/syst/arm9-linux-abtrack/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/lib/ -laxl -lm" AXL_CFLAGS=-I/shared/syst/arm9-linux-abtrack/package/host/aspl.es/axl-0.5.6/include/axl CC=/package/host/myvendor.com/arm9-linux-toolchain-2.1/prefix/bin/arm-linux-gcc LDFLAGS="-L/package/host/myvendor.com/arm9-linux-toolchain-2.1/prefix/arm-linux/lib" ~/wd/sources/contrib/vortex/configure --prefix=/shared/syst/arm9-linux-abtrack/package/host/aspl.es/vortex-1.1.0 --disable-http-support --disable-pull-support --disable-tunnel-support --disable-xml-rpc-support-gen --disable-xml-rpc-support --disable-sasl-support --disable-vortex-log --disable-vortex-client --host=armv4tl-unknown-linux-gnu && make

Any autofoo tips for embedding --prefix in compiled libraries?

Comment: LDFLAGS=/path configure is wrong.  You should instead do configure LDFLAGS=/path. That is, give the configure script the settings as arguments rather than setting them in the environment of configure.  This allows config.status to properly maintain the settings.  This may be part of the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add a possible answer anyways.

Just based on the info you've given, could it be that the full path names aren't included for aspl because the aspl libraries you've specified are soft links? If you do a long list on, for instance, /package/host/aspl.es/vortex-1.1.0/lib/libvortex-1.1.so it will show that it's a link to libvortex-1.1.so.0 (with no full pathname).

So, if you still want to embedded the full path, then you need to use the full path to the actual library, not the linked library.