# Force absolute path for shared library without LD_RUN_PATH

Tags: g++, shared-libraries, ld

I am trying to link a locally installed shared library (`./vendor/lib/libfoo.so`) with my binary, `./bar`. Unfortunately, none of my attempts generates a link with an absolute path to `libfoo.so`. As a consequence I need to use

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=vendor/lib ./bar
```

to run it, which I want to avoid. `ldd bar` shows me this:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffed5fd8000)
    libbar.so.2 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb9ea787000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb9ea47d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb9ea267000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb9e9e9d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055f326761000)
```

A word about `libbar.so.2`: the file exists (in `vendor/lib`) alongside `libbar.so`. Both are actually symlinks to `libhts.so.1.6`. That file also exists, and is the actual shared library.

Here’s the different ways I’ve tried:

```bash
FULL_PATH="$(pwd -P)/vendor/lib"

g++ -o bar bar.o -Lvendor/lib -lfoo        # 1
g++ -o bar bar.o -L$FULL_PATH -lfoo        # 2
g++ -o bar bar.o $FULL_PATH/libfoo.so      # 3
g++ -o bar bar.o $FULL_PATH/libfoo.so.1.6  # 4
```

*All* of these variants produce identical `ldd` output, *even the last line* (does `ld` insist on using the highest version of a library?).

The only way I’ve found to make this work is to use

```bash
LD_RUN_PATH=$FULL_PATH g++ -o bar bar.o -Lvendor/lib -lfoo
```

(I can’t use `-rpath` because my version of `g++` doesn’t understand this argument, and I’m using `g++` instead of `ld` to get the libstdc++ dependencies right — I could use `-Wl,-rpath` of course.)

But I can’t help but feel that there should be a way of making this work without the use of environment variables/`-rpath`. I’ve found [an answer specifically referencing symlinks to libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708242/1968) but unfortunately it doesn’t help me (see attempt 4 above).

This is on Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4.0, GNU ld 2.26.1, in case it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds likely that you didn't update the [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) cache after installing
your shared library in the non-standard location `/what/ever/vendor/lib`:-

```
sudo ldconfig /what/ever/vendor/lib
```

Until you do that the runtime linker will be unaware that `libfoo.so` is
in `/what/ever/vendor/lib`, even if it is, unless you prompt it at runtime through
the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Incidentally, it isn't a shortcoming of your version of `g++` that it
doesn't recognize `-rpath`. This has only ever been a linker (`ld`) option,
never a GCC frontend option. So `-Wl,-rpath=/what/ever/vendor/lib` is the
conventional way of tacking the non-standard runtime library path to your
program so as to avoid relying on either the `ldconfig` cache or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

For out-of-the ordinary linkages it may be considered better to use `-rpath`
rather than extend the `ldconfig` cache, which has less discriminate effects.

Comment: ”Until you do that the runtime linker will be unaware that `libfoo.so` is in `/what/ever/vendor/lib`” — right, that’s why I wanted to compile the binary with an absolute path to the library, so that `ld.so` doesn’t need to search for it (I don’t have superuser rights). But I’m starting to see that `-rpath` is the conventional solution here; I’m just puzzled why `ld` would ignore my explicit use of absolute paths.